# Does going sublime chord make use magic device redundant?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, prestige-class

As the title said, i was wondering if going sublime chord make putting points in use magic device redundant?

Comment: this question's pretty short.  could you add some context as to why you would think this?

Answer (score 5):

No; a sublime chord can use magic items of bard, sorcerer, and wizard spells, but not of any spells not on those lists. Cleric, druid, even specialist lists like assassin, paladin, and ranger, have useful things that sublime chords don’t otherwise have access to. And then there’s cheesy stuff like trapsmith, which gets stuff like 1st-level *haste*.

Comment: Don't forget things like emulating a specific race or class for special item usage.